# Android override Theme.Dialog windowTitleStyle property for AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, overriding, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I'm using AlertDialog.Builder like this:

```
ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cw);
```

This is my custom AlertDialogTheme style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/custom_style</item>
</style>
```

The `textSize` attribute works fine for the list of items I put in the builder with `builder.setItems()`, but it doesn't work on the title, so I've tried to override the `windowTitleStyle` attribute, but it doesn't work.

Is it even possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having similar issues, and I've done just what you have. One thing to note is that windowTitleStyle isn't used in the dialog title before API 14. Before that it was textAppearanceMedium. And in the default (pre-holo) dialog it is textAppearanceLarge.

Unfortunately, I'm setting all three of these to my custom style and testing in KK, but it still doesn't update the color as I'm expecting.